# Compiler error when calling function in other module

Tags: vba, excel, office-2010

In a VBA macro in Excel, I'm attempting to call a function from one module in another module.

I am able to successfully call a function in another module... but only if I disregard the return value from the function.

When I attempt to call a function in another module and save the return value
**`(MyReturnValue = Application.Run "Module2.MyFunctionInAnotherModule")`**, I get a Compiler Error:  "Expected: end of statement".

Clearly I'm getting something wrong in the syntax of that statement, but I have been unable to find the right syntax.

**Module1:**

```
Public Sub WhatGives()
Dim MyReturnValue As String

    ' Calling a subroutine in another module works
    Application.Run "Module2.MySub"

    MyReturnValue = MyFunctionInThisModule
    MsgBox ("MyFunctionInThisModule( ) returned:  " & MyReturnValue)

    ' Calling a function in another module works if
    ' I discard the return value of the function
    Application.Run "Module2.MyFunctionInAnotherModule"

    ' But calling a function and saving its return
    ' value doesn't work. When I uncomment the following
    ' statements, the second one results in the
    ' compiler error: "Expected: end of statement"
    'Dim MyReturnValue As String
    'MyReturnValue = Application.Run "Module2.MyFunctionInAnotherModule"
    'MsgBox("MyFunctionInAnotherModule( ) returned:  " & MyReturnValue)

End Sub

Private Function MyFunctionInThisModule()
    MsgBox ("MyFunctionInThisModule() invoked")
    MyFunctionInThisModule = "Return value from MyFunctionInThisModule"
End Function
```

**Module 2:**

```
Private Sub MySub()
    MsgBox ("MySub( ) invoked")
End Sub

Private Function MyFunctionInAnotherModule() As String
    MsgBox ("MyFunctionInAnotherModule( ) invoked")
    MyFunctionInAnotherModule = "Return value from MyFunctionInAnotherModule"
End Function
```

Comment: Is there a reason that function cannot be made **Public**?

Comment: ```MyReturnValue = Application.Run ("Module2.MyFunctionInAnotherModule")```?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return your value to something.
Try `xyz = Module2.MyFunctionInAnotherModule`

edit: Sorry, you'll also need to remove Private from your Function.

```
Function MyFunctionInAnotherModule() As String
    MsgBox ("MyFunctionInAnotherModule( ) invoked")
    MyFunctionInAnotherModule = "Return value from MyFunctionInAnotherModule"
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, Sam. Unfortunately removing "Private" from the  the function didn't work. Same compiler error.

Comment: Interesting. I was able to call it with no problems. Did you try calling it with xyz = Module2.MyFunctionInAnotherModule? i.e. remove Application.Run and the quotation marks.